Why did the angel strain or dislocate Yaakov's hip-socket?
When the angel of Eisav was struggling with Yaakov, in Bereishis 32:26 the verse states:

וַיַּ֗רְא כִּ֣י לֹ֤א יָכֹל֙ ל֔וֹ וַיִּגַּ֖ע בְּכַף־יְרֵכ֑וֹ וַתֵּ֙קַע֙ כַּף־יֶ֣רֶךְ יַעֲקֹ֔ב בְּהֵאָֽבְק֖וֹ עִמּֽוֹ׃
When he saw that he had not prevailed against him, he wrenched Jacob’s hip at its socket, so that the socket of his hip was strained (or dislocated) as he wrestled with him.

As a result of the fight, Yaakov was limping (Bereishis 32:32)
Why did the angel injure Yaakov in this specific way, and why was it necessary that Yaakov have difficulty walking or running?

Maybe it was payback for Yaakov grabbing Esav's leg.

@shmosel cute, Yaakov did not injure Eisav.

Radak on Bereshit 32:26 says it was a sin to be fearful and doubt Hashem's promises, for which he was punished:

היה לו זה מאת האל להיות בו זה לאות לפי שהיה פושע במחשבתו אחר כמה
הבטחות אשר עשה עמו האל מדה כנגד מדה להיות פוסח בגופו; כי אע"פ שהיה
בוטח באל בכל לבו אלא שחשב שמא יגרום החטא, אעפ"כ אחר כמה הבטחות לא היה
לו להרהר ולחוש לעשו ולקראו כמה פעמים אחי ולשלוח לו מנחה גדולה ולהשתחות
לו כמה פעמים, ובזה חטא, ושלם לו האל בזה העולם ולקה בגופו עונש מחשבת
This [the limping] was a sign from G’d, a reprisal of a kind, for the
doubts he had expressed about the various promises G’d had made him.
G’d now punished him by making him unable to rely on parts of his body
that he was in the habit of relying on. True, Yaakov trusted G’d with
all his heart, but he was in a constant state of worry that the
promises he had received would not come true due to some sin he had
committed. Considering that G’d’s promise had been repeated on
different occasions, proving that in the interval Yaakov had not
forfeited his claim to them, he should no longer have doubted that G’d
would not keep His promise for whatever reason. His servile behaviour
towards Esau, including the many times he called him adoni, “my lord,”
implied a lack of trust in the validity of G’d’s promises to him.
Neither should he have sent him such an elaborate gift, nor should he
have prostrated himself before him repeatedly. By doing so he
committed a sin and G’d punished him in this life by afflicting his
body, retribution already for planning to do this. [borrowed Eli
Munk's translation/explanation]

He should have relied on Hashem, and because he didn't, mida k'negged mida, he was punished by not being able to rely on his leg.
Why the hip socket?
Alshich
The hip socket is related to having children due to the phrase "יוצאי יריכו" is used by the Torah to refer to one's children. The angel was able to dislocate the hip because he found a flaw there - the fact that Yaacov married sisters. This point is explained (in slightly different ways) by various commentaries, such as Radak, Sforno.
Kitzur Ba'al HaTurim
He explains the angel touched the thigh to see if there was a joint there, because angels don't have joints. He also wanted to make a flaw in the Kehuna, and the phrase "בכף ירכו" has the same gematria as לפוסלו מכהונה, disqualified from the Kehuna.
Chatam Sofer
He explains that this is a hint at the destruction of the Beit Hamikdash, and the connection is the word "ירך", which, according to the Shalah, is three letters representing represents Torah, Torah learning, and the Beit Hamikdash respectively (the כ is for כסא, an allusion to the Beit Hamikdash), and also is pronounced kaf, which means "hollow", and that is reference to the hollow of the thigh.

Could you please add regarding "rely on parts of his body that he was in the habit of relying on", how is it necessarily the hip-socket?

Thank you. However these are mystical reasons. Is there a pshat?

@YDJ Rav Hirsch might be pshat. He seems to indicate that he tried to lift Yaacov, but couldn't, so grabbed his thigh, and Yaacov dislocated it himself when he tried to pull away.

That would go against Radak

@YDJ the best I can do is assume Radak thought the hip, because Yaacov bowed to Esav.

There has to be an answer along the lines that Yaakov ran away in Vayeitzei from Eisav and then from Lavan. And this time - no more running away, while he actually planned: if one camp gets hit, the second will run away. This fits very well with Radak!

In addition to the earlier answer:
-The Rashbam says the angel came to prevent Jacob from escaping from Esau.  God wants the brothers to meet, so sends the angel to dislocate Jacob's hip joint, thereby laming him and preventing any possibility of escape.  The lesson is: You may not run away from your troubles.
-The Ramban says that the angel came to warn against antisemites:  The whole matter represents an allusion to our future history, that there would come a time when the descendants of Esau would overcome Jacob almost to the point of total destruction. This happened during the days of the Sages of the Mishnah... There were other generations who did... worse things to us. But we endured all and it passed us by. [Also in Lekach Tov]  The antisemites may wound us, as the entity wounded Jacob's hip, but they will not destroy us.  After that incident, the Torah says: "וַיָּבֹא֩ יַעֲקֹ֨ב שָׁלֵ֜ם עִ֣יר שְׁכֶ֗ם  Jacob arrived whole (shalem) in the city of Shechem". [Gen. 33:18] The battle will end “at the break of dawn”, which is the time of the final Redemption.
-Rabbenu Baḥya says the angel came to find a sin Jacob was guilty of, to use it as a weapon to overpower him. He did not succeed. The only sin he could find was that Jacob had married two sisters during their lifetime, something the Torah later forbade.  The writing: “He inflicted an injury on Jacob’s hip joint” is a euphemism for his sexual organ and the seat of sexual desire. The punishment was administered near that organ so that Jacob limped for a while.  The Zohar [1:170b] makes a similar point.

Actually, your answer does not have links. Could you please provide links to sources? Thank you.

@YDJ -- They have to be comments on Bereshit 32:26.

Rashbam says: the angel did not succeed in preventing Yaakov from crossing and fleeing. It is different and not about thigh. It is different from your words and not about a thigh. https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.32.26?lang=bi&with=Rashbam&lang2=bi

The Ramban's comment is close, but it is not about a thigh either. https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.32.26?lang=bi&with=Ramban&lang2=bi. Rabbeinu Bachya makes a similar connection.

@YDJ -- The Rashbam must have said it somewhere else.  I quickly found a site that quotes him as I said:  https://booksnthoughts.com/what-prompted-jacob-to-wrestle-with-an-angel/

It seems that the answer is that the angel's act became valid only in the morning. I.e. Rashbam means that, after the angel left,  Yaakov was able to escape across the river (as there was still time), but when the sun rose, Yaakov started limping and could not run away from Eisav.
